# configuring thunderbird for imap access gmail ubuntu 19.10

Tags: vmware, email, thunderbird, 19.10, gmail

I am doing all this on Ubuntu 19.10 in thunderbird default application which is installed with OS.
I am having problem in configuring thunderbird in VMware environment.
I am using VMware 15 workstation. 
I have problem in using Gmail I discussed them here https://superuser.com/questions/1502126/13-66-gb-out-of-15-gb-used-in-gmail-delete-emails-that-consumed-space now I want to try the suggestion given to me.
So I started configuring thunderbird in ubuntu19.10  in VMware
Every thing was automatic I did not enter any values except my username and password. But I got error as shown in screenshot.
[image: thunderbird problem]
In my Gmail settings I checked POP3 and IMAP are allowed. So how do I configure thunderbird in this environment to work.

Comment: all I can say is "ditto", this seems to be some finicky configuration I'm guessing.

Comment: I lost all my emails some panicky thing happened and all that I did to save my emails are lost from gmail. The only thing I am left with a Ubuntu 19.10 Virtual machine running in Vmware which has thunderbird installed some messages are downloaded however it is difficult to read them.